# How can I get the word after a string?

Tags: php, strpos

I have a string which somewhere contains `Style Name: Something`. What I want to be able to do is search for `Style Name:` and get back `Something` or whatever that value is.

I know I need to do something with `strpos` to search the string but I'm pretty much stuck on getting the value.

Comment: with regex https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With positive lookbehind,

```
<?php
$string="Style Name: Something with colorful";
preg_match('/(?<=Style Name: )\S+/i', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/OICqF

Comment: If this be the actual requirement, it might be easier to just split on `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match_all`:

```
$input = "Sample text Style Name: cats and also this Style Name: dogs";
preg_match_all("/\bStyle Name:\s+(\S+)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cats
    [1] => dogs
)
```

The pattern used `\bStyle Name:\s+(\S+)` matches `Style Name:` followed by one or more spaces.  Then, it matches and captures the next word which follows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex.
Two simple explodes and you got the style name.

```
$str = "something something Style Name: Something some more text";

$style_name = explode(" ",explode("Style Name: ", $str)[1])[0];

echo $style_name; // Something
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make use of `\K` to forget what was matched and match 0+ times a horizontal whitespace `\h*`:

```
\bStyle Name:\h*\K\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ixc8nQ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/MlHJm)

```
$re = '/\bStyle Name:\h*\K\S+/m';
$str = 'Style Name: Something Style Name: Something Style Name: Something';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Something
    [1] => Something
    [2] => Something
)
```